# Is there an option in SourceTree / Git to review another persons code before pushing?

Tags: git, version-control, push, verify

We use SourceTree for a project at work. Because all team members are inexperienced juniors, we see a lot of code that isn't exactly high quality.

Therefore, we want to include a step that forces you to let your code check by another team member before you can push your code. Is this already a built-in option in SourceTree or Git?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have them commit to a branch and then create a pull request, assigning it to the reviewer of the code, who will have to approve/merge it into the master/nightly.

In SourceTree the option is under the Repository menu item at the bottom.

Comment: I wonder if you can truly make a code review consisting of multiple commits in Source Tree, the way GitHub and BitBucket do it. Basically, preview several commits as a cumulative diff.